# split a phone-number field with different delimiters into three different fields

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I want to convert a CSV field into three columns based on these three delimiters: Forward Slash, a dash, and a Close Parenthesis: **)/-**

```
(031)540-6622
021-886-3877
555/532-2662
```

And here is what I need to see:

```
031  540  6622
021   886  3877
555   532   2662
```

Actually, I seek a simple and fast method that can convert the following pattern:

```
(###)###-####       \
###-###-####         |---> ###-###-####
###/###-####        /
```

And then convert the dash-seperated field into three field with space delimiter.

Comment: if you are using `GNU awk`, you can use `FPAT` or `patsplit` to match digits so that you are defining field content instead of splitting.. that'll work with any delimiter.. `perl` is another option is you don't have `GNU awk`.. also, it might be better to show how sample input rows to indicate whether your input has only this phone field or some other content.. `sed` isn't typically suited for field processing, but it might suit in this case.. and, you could also add what you've tried yourself to solve this

Comment: start by converting all the delimiters into a comma. And what is special about the `(`?

Comment: In the UK there are recommendations on how to split phone numbers. Almost no one does it this way. People often don't know where the area code ends (we have variable length aria codes). Therefore for UK codes I just remove delimiters, and then use the recommendations to put them back.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. Please see the edited post.

Answer (score 1):

With GNU sed. Remove leading `(` and replace `-`, `)` and `/` with a space:

```
sed 's/^(//; y|-)/|   |' file
```

Output:

```
031 5440 6622
021 8886 3877
555 532 2662
```

Comment: Simple and pretty approach. Merci Cyrus.

Answer (score 1):

## Option 1

If your data consistently has three blocks of digits with any delimiter, this should do it:

```
grep -Eo "[0-9]+" phone.txt \
  | paste -d- - - -
```

This will **not** work correctly if any phone number deviates from three blocks. Though not one of your requirements, due to how it operates it also **should** work if a line contains multiple phone numbers, or a phone number is broken across multiple lines — as long as each number contains exactly three blocks.

### Breakdown

```
grep -Eo "[0-9]+" phone.txt
```

Extracts sequential blocks of digits, results are broken down with one block per line.

```
paste -d- - - -
```

Unwrap the data so that 3 blocks appear per line with hyphen as delimiter.

## Option 2

Alternatively, if your data is a bit less consistent:

```
sed -r 's/[^0-9]+/-/g;s/^-//;s/-$//' phone.txt
```

### Breakdown

`s/[^0-9]+/-/g` replace any non-numerical with hyphen

`s/^-//` remove any leading hyphens

`s/-$//` remove any trailing hyphens

Answer (score 1):

> I want to convert a CSV field into three columns based on these three delimiters: Forward Slash, a dash, and a Close Parenthesis: `)/-`

with  `awk` you can set `FS` with those 3 delimiters and get 3 columns and remove the initial `(` from the first column:

```
awk -v FS='[)-/]' '{gsub(/^\(/,"",$1);print $1,$2,$3}' file
031 540 6622
021 886 3877
555 532 2662
```